Young adult sci-fi novel about a teenage female and a small group of other teenagers raised in a high tech society with mind link capabilities
I'm searching for the name of a young adult novel I read between 2003-2008. I live in Western Australia and borrowed the novel from a local public library. It was written in English. I think it was part of a series, but I'm not 100% sure.
The protagonist was a teenage female living in a society with advanced technology that allowed some form of mind link capabilities. The protagonist and a small group of other teenagers had been raised by those in power (may have been a corporation?) and had more advanced capabilities than normal citizens, equal to being able to access the internet in her mind. She was particularly close to one of the boys she was raised alongside, and I remember he referred to everyone else as being like 'trees', while their group were the 'forest.' Before the novel begins, she had either been exiled or chose to leave the group she grew up with. I think this was linked to information she discovered about those in charge, but I can't quite remember.
At the beginning of the first novel, something occurred which prompted the protagonist to leave her place of exile, and I'm pretty sure she teams up with a different boy, but I don't remember much about him. I remember she interacts with a centaur early on, and that later on in the novel (or series), there were some form of vampiric creatures/ creatures who drank blood, although they didn't necessarily kill people. However, I think these fantastical elements were explained by science/ technology rather than magic.
The overall tone of the novel was definitely YA and had a bit of a romance focus.

Could this be the Dark Visions trilogy by L. J. Smith?
It doesn't match 100 percent, but it involves a girl with psychic powers (premonitions of the future) who is offered a place at a psychic research centre, where she meets others with psychic abilities.  The books involve some sort of dark crystal that turns people into "psychic vampires" that feed on other people's psychic energy.
I didn't see any mention of a centaur, though.
